# colNames newLine in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have `colNames: ['1, 2, 3, first second third']` consists of several words. Can I move the `second` and `third` word to a new line?

[image: example]

Comment: You could try the new line character, like `first \n second third`

Comment: This method does not work

Comment: You could include enough code to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so people can play around and suggest a possibly answer

Answer (score 0):

The content of elements of `colNames` represents HTML fragments, which will be placed in the column header. Thus you can use for example you can use `"first<br>second third"` as an element of `colNames`.